# How to render events in FullCalendar from JSON in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I've been able to get FullCalendar to load in my webpage but I can't seem to successfully pass my test JSON data to the calendar and have it render events. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm following this [website's example](http://venkatbaggu.com/calendar-in-asp-net-mvc/) and I even downloaded their source code and was able to run it successfully in my dev environment. My code seems to almost completely mirror their's yet I still can't render events. I even went back and added javascript files to my bundles just in case that was the issue but to no success.

Any ideas?

Bundles:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css",
                  "~/Content/fullcalendar.css"));

        /*Kendo UI Instructions that were followed
         * http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-5
        */
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo").Include(
        "~/Scripts/kendo/2016.2.714/kendo.webcomponents.min.js",
        // "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.timezones.min.js", // uncomment if using the Scheduler
        "~/Scripts/kendo/2016.2.714/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/kendo/2016.2.714/jquery.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/kendo/2016.2.714/kendo.ui.core.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/kendo/2016.2.714/kendo.calendar.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/kendo/2016.2.714/kendo.popup.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/kendo/2016.2.714/kendo.datepicker.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo/css").Include(
            "~/Content/kendo/2016.2.714/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css",
            "~/Content/kendo/2016.2.714/kendo.bootstrap.min.css",
            "~/Content/kendo/2016.2.714/kendo.common.min.css",
            "~/Content/kendo/2016.2.714/kendo.defualt.min.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/fullcalendar").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/moment.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js"));

        bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();


    }
```

_Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Time Zone Event Calendar</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fullcalendar")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Time Zone Event Calendar", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Time Zone Event Calendar</p>
        </footer>
    </div>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Index:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<head>
    @section scripts{
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
                {
                    header:
                    {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    editable: false,
                    events: "/home/loadevents/"

                })
            });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#pickDateTime").kendoDateTimePicker({
                    culture: "es-Es",
                    interval: 1,
                    format: "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm tt",
                    parseFormats: ["MMMM yyyy", "HH:mm"]

                });

            });
        </script>
    }
</head>

<body>
    <div id="headerBar">
        <div id="datepicker">
            <form method="post">
                <input id="pickDateTime" name="DateTimePicker" />
                <input type="submit" value="Add" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="calendar"></div>


</body>
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult LoadEvents (double start, double end)
    {
        var fromDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start);
        var toDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end);

        var eventList = GetEvents();

        var rows = eventList.ToArray();

        return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    private List<CalendarEventsViewModel> GetEvents()
    {
        List<CalendarEventsViewModel> eventList = new List<CalendarEventsViewModel>();

        CalendarEventsViewModel newEvent = new CalendarEventsViewModel
        {
            ID = "1",
            EventName = "Event 1",
            StartDateString = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("s"),
            EndDateString = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("s"),
            AllDay = false
        };


        eventList.Add(newEvent);

        newEvent = new CalendarEventsViewModel
        {
            ID = "1",
            EventName = "Event 3",
            StartDateString = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString("s"),
            EndDateString = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString("s"),
            AllDay = false
        };

        eventList.Add(newEvent);

        return eventList;
    }

    private static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
    {
        var origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp);
    }

}
```

CalendarEventsViewModel:

```
public class CalendarEventsViewModel
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public string EventText { get; set; }
    public string StartDateString { get; set; }
    public string EndDateString { get; set; }
    public bool AllDay { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Which version of fullcalendar are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have made the same mistake I did when I first set it up, the example you are looking at only works for version one of FullCalendar. In version two it's not a unix timestamp your LoadEvents action receives.

It's a moment object that is passed to the action, if you remove your ConvertFromUnixTimestamp method and change your start and end parameters from double to DateTime I think it will start working.

If you break point your LoadEvents action without making any changes I am pretty confident it's not even being called.

Your property names should match those of the [event object](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) otherwise it will treat them like non standard fields.

Comment: I didn't even notice the library version. I made the changes and nothing seemed to happen. I checked the action and it is getting called by the javascript but it's still not displaying the events.

Comment: When you inspect the page are the jQuery and Moment scripts loaded before the FullCalendar script?

Comment: I think the property names on your event object should match the actual event object http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_data/Event_Object/

You are passing it a JSON feed, it will be seeing your current properties as non standard fields. Update it to match them and you may have more success.

Comment: Yes:

`<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
--kendo scripts, too many to list here--
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You were correct I needed to change my properties to the ones it was expecting. I have no idea why I assumed it would just know what I was passing it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, that's good you have it working. I went through all of these issues when I first used it :-)

Comment: Answer updated for anyone that happens to look at this question.

Comment: Works for me, Thank you!